# Should a question be closed for being off topic if it has an accepted answer that is on topic?

Tags: discussion

Consider [EB Garamond percentage glyph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701131/eb-garamond-percentage-glyph)

The closing message says that the comments should explain why the question was closed. I don't think they do.

One could argue that the question as formulated is not strictly about TeX but I think that the accepted answer is very much about TeX so I am not convinced. Am I missing something?

Comment: The problem with the question is that "Could it be that this is some sort of placeholder symbol that go forgotten about? Who can say" is not a latex problem, but a question to the designer of the font. If you could narrow the question down to "can something be done?", it would be a reasonable question for a latex Q&A site and I'd happily vote to reopen. You could emphasis it even more being a latex question by adding a MWE which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Fair enough, done ☑

Comment: Why not completely remove your speculations about it being a placeholder symbols? This does not add anything to the question. Also your first sentence is not that useful to have in the question.